# Will DATETIME(3) data type work for Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

For MySQL, to specify the data type date time, then you must use the keyword `DATETIME`. But it will only give you normal time. Not milliseconds.

```
mysql> SELECT col,
     >     CAST(col AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '+00:00' AS DATETIME) AS ut
     >     FROM ts ORDER BY id;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| col                 | ut                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-01-01 10:10:10 | 2020-01-01 15:10:10 |
| 2019-12-31 23:40:10 | 2020-01-01 04:40:10 |
| 2020-01-01 13:10:10 | 2020-01-01 18:10:10 |
| 2020-01-01 10:10:10 | 2020-01-01 15:10:10 |
| 2020-01-01 04:40:10 | 2020-01-01 09:40:10 |
| 2020-01-01 18:10:10 | 2020-01-01 23:10:10 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

To get in milliseconds, one must use `DATETIME(3)` and for microseconds, one must use `DATETIME(6)`.

But for Microsoft SQL Server, then `DATETIME` will give you `hh:mm:ss:mmm` by default.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5993/sql-server-date-and-time-functions-with-examples/

**Question:**

What will happen if I used `DATETIME(3)` in Microsoft SQL Server?
Will I get an error, or will it give me the time stamp `hh:mm:ss:mmm` as it was default?

I don't have Microsoft SQL Server. Only MySQL, but I'm trying to make my C++ code compatible with both SQL servers.

Comment: Use dbfiddle to check. Or check the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: yes, try it out: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l

Comment: I've tried to make SQL code that is compatible between different brands of SQL implementations. It's often not possible, despite the SQL language being based on a common standard specification. Every brand introduces their own custom features. If you restrict your code only to features that are the same across different brands, then you can't use any of the unique, valuable features each brand offers.

Comment: You need DATETIME2 in SQL Server if you want to specify precision

Comment: @BillKarwin I understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default datetime datatype returns with precision of milliseconds. The milli second values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds.[Datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
SELECT GETDATE()
```

> 2022-01-31 03:02:58.997

But, if you want to specify the precision, you can go with datetime2 datatype. Datetime2 is ANSI standard and it is accurate to 100 nano seconds.

```sql
DECLARE @datetime2literal datetime2(3) = '2022-01-10 10:22:33.1234567'
SELECT @datetime2literal
```

> 2022-01-10 10:22:33.123

I would suggest you to go with `DATETIME2` as it is coming with less storage with more precision and also ANSI Standard. [DateTime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Advantages of Datetime2**
[Reference article](https://database.guide/datetime-vs-datetime2-in-sql-server-whats-the-difference/)

- larger date range
- larger default fractional precision
- optional user-specified precision
- higher accuracy, even when using using the same number of decimal places as datetime (i.e. 3)
- less storage size when using using the same number of decimal places as datetime, yet with higher accuracy*
  the option to use 2 bytes less storage than datetime (albeit with lower precision)*
- aligns with the SQL standards (ANSI & ISO 8601)

Comment: Did you mean for your datetime2 link to come back to this answer?

Comment: @BenThul, Thanks for checking. I have updated the link now.